# What does "write-off" mean?

Tags: taxes, accounting

I've heard this term throughout my life but I've never been entirely sure exactly what it means or why you would want to write something off.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write-off) also gives it a decent treatment.

> The term write-off describes a reduction in recognized value. In accounting terminology, it refers to recognition of the reduced or zero value of an asset. In income tax statements, it refers to a reduction of taxable income as recognition of certain expenses required to produce the income. Write-off is also used in vehicle insurance to describe a vehicle which is cheaper to replace than to repair, sometimes colloquially referred to as being "totaled" (a total loss). Write-off is the act of creating Debit payment against the Credit and vice-versa, to nullify the transaction.

For income tax purposes it is synonymous with "deduction."  The Wikipedia article provides some examples of a few types of write-offs.

Answer (score 3):

The term "write-off" is usually applied in the annual accounting/audit process.  It can act to reduce a tax liability.

It is applied to capital assets which have either become redundant (replaced by upgrades) or which no longer serve a purpose (even if they are still usable).  This allows their value to be reduced to zero and "written" out of the company's asset register.

Answer (score 2):

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/write_off) gives a pretty accurate and straight-forward definition:

> 1. (accounting) To reduce an asset's book value to zero
> 2. (accounting) To record an expenditure as an expense.
> 3. (accounting) To record a notional expense such as amortization
>      or depreciation.
> 4. Figuratively, to assign a low value to something.
>
>    ```
>    When Katya was injured, he wrote off the team's chances in the finals.
>    ```